# optgroup class gets applied to all sub-options in FF, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an optgroup like this:

```
 <optgroup label="Eller välj Län" title="Eller välj Län" style="background-color:#FC9;">
 <option value="Blekinge Län">Blekinge</option>
 <option value="Dalarna Län">Dalarna</option>
 <option value="Gotlands Län">Gotland</option>
 </optgroup>
```

Problem is, only in Firefox, the class applies to all options inside the optgroup.
I need it to apply only to the optgroup label...

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the "cascading" part of "Cascading Style Sheets". You'll need to explicitly set the background colors of the options (preferably in the external style sheet and not in-line):

```
optgroup {
  background-color: #FC9;
}

optgroup option {
  background-color: white; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: I think that's the "inheritance" part. In CSS, styles never cascade across elements. But *my* take is that "cascading" was a total misnomer :)